# Fade Toggle Animate addClass

Tags: jquery, css, addclass

I'm new to this forum and got a question to fading/animating toggle or addClass values...

Here is my jQuery:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

 $j(function(){
     $j(".fitsize").toggle(function() {
         $j(".hgwrapper").addClass("wrapperfit"); 
         $j(".hgwrapper").removeClass("hgwrapper");
         $j(".imageholder").addClass("holderfit");
         $j(".imageholder").removeClass("imageholder");
         $j(".hg").addClass("fit", 500);
         $j(".hg").removeClass("hg");
     },
     function() {
         $j(".wrapperfit").addClass("hgwrapper");
         $j(".wrapperfit").removeClass("wrapperfit");
         $j(".holderfit").addClass("imageholder");
         $j(".holderfit").removeClass("holderfit");
         $j(".fit").addClass("hg", 500);
         $j(".fit").removeClass("fit");
     });
 });
```

You can see it live here: http://entwicklung.elvividor.com.

I would really appreciate if someone has an answer to my question if there's a way to animate this change of css classes. I tried making transitions in css, but this had no effects.

Maybe there's someone who has an idea?

Maiskolben

Comment: To animate a element the property that is being animated should have a  numeric value

Comment: just use a plugin like http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ it does everything for you

Comment: Hey, thanks! But this malsup Script fades between two pictures. Not really what I wanted. I just need to know if I can easily animate between my two classes for one pic. Or if theres another way to set new css (width and height) after clicking "Fit to screen". LG Maiskolben